# Can't insert data after making associations - Rails on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm starting a Rails on Ruby course and i've just gotten to the Associations part. I have the following association: An Alien belongs to a Planet, and said planed can have many aliens.

My planet.rb:

```
class Planet < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :aliens
end
```

My alien.rb:

```
class Alien < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :planet
end
```

I have 2 planets inserted as seen in

```
Planet Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "planets".* FROM "planets"
 => #<Enumerator: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Planet id: 1, nome: "planeta loko", created_at: "2016-09-15 19:49:28", updated_at: "2016-09-15 19:49:28">, #<Planet id: 2, nome: "planeta2", created_at: "2016-09-15 19:49:49", updated_at: "2016-09-15 19:49:49">]
```

So i was told to insert the data for aliens like so:

```
p = Planet.find(1)  
a = Alien.create(nome: "x", age: "1", planet: p)
```

It doesn't work though, i get this error:

```
a = Alien.create(nome: "x", age: "1", planet: p)
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `planet_id`
```

Any idea of what is causing this?
Also, sorry in advance for any gramatical errors as english is not my mother language. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you have field planet_id in table aliens?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add the planet_id column. Check your db/schema.rb or your database. You need this foreign key to associate aliens with planets.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your migrations. It seems like you did not add the foreign key for aliens in planet.